# Two Toolbars Showing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

[image]

I recently added a CoordinatorLayout to my Application. How do i remove blue box, which is showing below the other toolbar. I already tried to remove the appbar layout and the navigation view, but they did not result in any changes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.recyclerviewtutorial.ChatListActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_chats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
       />


</LinearLayout>
```

*Edit* Styles.xml was added.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

*Just some random text to meet the posting requirements*
*Edit* **Problem is solved ty**

I added an ID to the AppBarLayout

```
android:id="@+id/appbar_nav"
```

and disabled it in the onCreate Method of the Activity.

```
AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appbar_nav);
mAppBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Show your styles.xml

Comment: set apptheme noactionbar

Comment: Use `NoActionBar` Theme .

Comment: you have to use `noactionbar` if you want custom toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Set this theme to your *styles.xml* file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
   <!-- <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

and give this style to activity in manifest like,

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
```

EXTRA :

if you want transparent status bar than add java code like,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set below theme as your application theme or as an Activity theme

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```